# devenv.exe and svchost.exe both hog an entire CPU and the hogging thread has the same function at the top of the stack trace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cpu-usage, devenv

I'm using visual studio 2010 SP1Rel with no extensions and the devenv.exe process continuously uses an entire core, making using the IDE very difficult, if not impossible. 
I've noticed that `svchost.exe -k netsvcs` is also using an entire core.
I've run Process Explorer to try to identify what is happening, and I noticed that both of these processes has one thread that is hogging all the CPU and both threads are in the same function `ntoskrnl.exe!KeSetEvent+0x6ca`  
The stack trace for svchost.exe is

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSetEvent+0x6ca
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xd52
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0xbb4
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0x1841
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0x1ab7
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x6c2c
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x6cd3
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x6977
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x116be
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x12177
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x2a702
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x27316
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x25a88
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x62e5
wuaueng.dll!DllInstall+0x59db
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

and the stack trace for devenv.exe is

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSetEvent+0x6ca
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xd52
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0xbb4
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0x1841
ntoskrnl.exe!PoStartNextPowerIrp+0x1ab7
cslangsvc.dll+0x5a08
cslangsvc.dll+0x5a7b
cslangsvc.dll+0x1f8cd
cslangsvc.dll+0x1fbae
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x328dc
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x32c5f
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x32655
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x327ff
cslangsvc.dll+0x308af
cslangsvc.dll+0x3079e
cslangsvc.dll+0x308af
cslangsvc.dll+0x3079e
cslangsvc.dll+0x308af
cslangsvc.dll!_BaseNodeOwner_Release@4+0x29901
cslangsvc.dll!_BaseNodeOwner_Release@4+0x298ba
cslangsvc.dll+0x3079e
cslangsvc.dll+0x308af
cslangsvc.dll+0x3079e
cslangsvc.dll+0x308af
cslangsvc.dll+0x23600
cslangsvc.dll+0x235b1
cslangsvc.dll+0x23600
cslangsvc.dll+0x235b1
cslangsvc.dll+0x23600
cslangsvc.dll+0x235b1
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x6279
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x2c8b4
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x2bb91
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x2bbb4
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x2b509
cslangsvc.dll!_LangService_IsRunningUnitTests@4+0xc3b
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x2b019
cslangsvc.dll!_FileCodeModel_GetTopLevelParseEvents@24+0x2acbb
cslangsvc.dll+0x255bb
cslangsvc.dll+0x2558c
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.ni.dll+0x4d5ea
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ni.dll+0xa17cc
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ni.dll+0xa16a1
clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0xaa94
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x14fbc3
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x14f740
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x14c867
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x1566a1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x1562fa
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x155cf6
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x1557af
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x153ed4
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x153e35
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x15a3a0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x153662
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x153075
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x15286f
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x15204e
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.ni.dll+0x16848e
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbb432
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbb36a
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbda3c
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbd988
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbd8ab
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xba23b
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xba3da
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbb61b
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbb56b
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbb432
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbb36a
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xb9b0e
WindowsBase.ni.dll+0xbaef1
clr.dll+0x2936
msenv.dll!DllGetClassObject+0x379b1
msenv.dll!DllGetClassObject+0x37521
msenv.dll!DllGetClassObject+0x375aa
msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x190f
msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x1840
msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x17a1
msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x176e
msenv.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x16b0
msenv.dll!VStudioMain+0x78
devenv.exe+0x10637
devenv.exe+0x10fd4
devenv.exe+0x120d8
devenv.exe+0x12148
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36
```

Has anyone seen this before? I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as I have no clue how to proceed. I've restarted visual studio multiple times and rebooted multiple time but to no avail. A couple minutes after launching VS, the problem with devenv.exe reoccurs and the svchost.exe -k netsvcs issues comes and goes.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but closing most of the files I had open in visual studio seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for a solution to this for years!  My computer gets really noisy when this happens.